# Is it a valid slash draw?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

Given a rectangle input with only `\`, `/` and space, decide if it's a valid output of [Drawing in Slashes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/37390/)

Empty lines and columns at edge get cleaned up, so the 3rd true case is true.

True cases:

```
 /\/\   
/ /\ \  
\/ /  \ 
/\/ /\ \
\  /  \/
 \ \    
  \ \   
   \/   

   /\/\ 
  / /\ \
 /  \ \/
/ /\ \/\
\/  \  /
    / / 
   / /  
   \/   

/\      
\/      
      /\
      \/
```

False cases:

```
 /\ 
/  \
\ \/
 \/ 

 /\ 
/  \
\  \
 \/ 

/\     
\/     
     /\
     \/
```

Shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: Aren't the third cases for each category the same?

Comment: @JoKing Different amount of space between, making one possible and one impossible

Comment: Challenges must be self-contained; please include the criteria for validity within the spec rather than relying on an outside source.

Comment: This seems like a good question, it just needs to be better specified.

Comment: @Shaggy Please provide a source of this rule

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 62 bytes

```
ＷＳ⊞υι≔Ｅ/\ΣＥυ⁺μ⌕Ａλιθ∧∧⬤υ¬﹪⁺№ι/№ι\²⬤Ｅ⌊υＥυ§λκ¬﹪⁺№ι/№ι\²⬤⊟θ⌊﹪⁺ι⌊θ²
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=nVDNSsQwEMZrnmLIaQpdAnsS9lQFcQ9dCns0Hmq7boNp0m4S9V287EHRV9KncdIGd88GAt98fD_DvH01XX1obK2Px4_gHxeXPxdXL53SO8C1GYLf-oMye8wyqILrMOSgshUrnFN7g2U9IBdS8hy2oZ9GElQ6OOxzuFGmLbRGHT3x5TCSt6JAj4Vp508C8mysx9K2QVuc7Nc2kEjlwAUn32mkshi0nOKiOZaWyqieFgjEpSUKvzbt7jWWP0XpfwpSQ2UHHGNyajmPUSd6_LNlq3f30Lh00M87vnjW_P77FoQUEgCYIASEmCQEhJiQM8eIjYxgMClIAwkRID6COfcX) Link is to verbose version of code. Takes input as a rectangular list of newline-terminated strings. Not actually sure this works in general, but posting anyway just in case.